# Durandal SPA issues with typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, durandal, typescript1.8

I am updated my durandal SPA application from VS_2012 to VS_2015 with TypeScript 1.8 which will generate JavaScript (ECMA5). I resolved all build errors.But I am unable to fix one typescript error called

**"A 'return' statement can only be used within a function body"**

I am working on view models. So I need return statement out side of function.

Due to build error I am not able to generate my java-script.

**Below is my sample code in Type script:**

```
class typescript1_8{
    constructor(){

    }
}
return new typescript1_8();
```

**Java Script code needs to generate like below:**

```
var typescript1_8 = (function () {
    function typescript1_8() {
    }
    return typescript1_8;
}());
return new typescript1_8();
```

**Note**: I need return statement outside of class. It shouldn't throw any error in Type script as mentioned on above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot just return something from empty space, you can use `Self-invoking` function

```
(function() {
    return new typescript1_8();
})();
```