# Durandal SPA Issues with knockout and typescript 1.8.4

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js, visual-studio-2015, durandal

I am working on MVVM Durandal SPA application with VS2012. Now I migrated to VS2015 with Typescript 1.8.4. I am working with typescript modules. All Typescript issues resolved. But Where ever I passed bindings with knockout all are showing as undefined in console. Due to return statement at end of view model(Module).

Build error was "Return statement can only be used within a function body".
If the solution was passing $root , then I need to pass show many places.

Is there any simple way to resolve this.

**Impacted Areas:** on View model end I need to write return statement. Like below type script code but it should generate JavaScript as mentioned below. If I fix build error then only I am able to generate JavaScript.

**Typescript working With Module:**

```
class Greeter {
    greeting: string;
    constructor(message: string) {
        this.greeting = message;
    }
    greet() {
        return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
    }
}
return Greeter;
```

**Generated JS Due to Build Error:**

```
define(["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {
    "use strict";
    var Greeter = (function () {
        function Greeter(message) {
            this.greeting = message;
        }
        Greeter.prototype.greet = function () {
            return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
        };
        return Greeter;
    }());

});
```

**Actual Need JS is:**

```
define(["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {
        "use strict";
        var Greeter = (function () {
            function Greeter(message) {
                this.greeting = message;
            }
            Greeter.prototype.greet = function () {
                return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
            };
            return Greeter;
        }());
        exports.Greeter = Greeter;
        return Greeter;
    });
```

But as per new typescript version 1.8 return shouldn't be an out side of function. I tried with some alternatives as for this [**Question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35798678/durandal-spa-issues-with-typescript/). But no use I need return statement as same as above code or else any alternative.

Note: With VS2012 Typescript generating ECMAScript3 and with VS2015 Typescript is generating ECMAScript5. I am using Knockout 2.3 and Durandal 2.0.1

**Image:**

[image]