# How to disable Typescript warning for return statements

Tags: typescript

I'd like to disable this warning for Typescript, since I am creating scripts that may have return value outside of a function body:

[image]

**[Better example on github gist](https://gist.github.com/FabianTe/2c4bef81795201bebd7b603833da56ea)**

The compiled script will be used by a system called DOCUMENTS which you probably haven't heard of. This system has it's own javascript engine based on Firefox's engine. In this custom engine, you may have script returns which will cause certain actions (showing a result, an error or a file download). Basically: The environment I use my transpiled .ts files in may have such return statements outside of functions.

Comment: It seems you want to execute some function as soon as this module is loaded. If this correct then you can use IIFE. Examples: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35798866/2270340, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/A_re-introduction_to_JavaScript#Functions

Comment: No you are not right. I'll post a better example in a minute

Comment: I saw your example. However, I am not sure about the use case here. For example, how do you intend to invoke(?) this typescript file (module)? Have you considered exporting stuffs from the module?

Comment: The compiled script will be used by a system called DOCUMENTS which you probably haven't heard of. This system has it's own javascript engine based on Firefox's engine. In this custom engine, you may have script returns which will cause certain actions (showing a result, an error or a file download). Basically: The environment I use my transpiled .ts files in may have such return statements outside of functions.

I updated my post accordingly.

Comment: It sounds like the real problem here is that your target platform operates outside the ES standards, and TS doesn't support it.

Comment: @coderer yes thats right. But sometimes thats just what you have to deal with. the Script i wrote back then was run in an embedded JS engine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot currently [silence selected errors](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9448) in TypeScript (as I see you have [found](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9448#issuecomment-319622540)). It looks like at least one TypeScript contributer is quite [opposed](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11051#issuecomment-248806829) to allowing this, so I wouldn't count on it happening.

The specific error you are seeing is [TS1108](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/2efaa7c9e2eca36876f127041262f0c392c874f4/src/compiler/diagnosticMessages.json#L310).  The error might annoy you but, unless you specify the `noEmitOnError` [compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html), it won't stop the compiler from producing the JavaScript output you expect.  As far as I can tell, your options are, in order of increasing difficulty:

- Ignore it
- Add a build step that processes the compiler output and filters out TS1108 errors
- Refactor your code and script engine so it is within a function body

Sorry the answer isn't what you like.  Hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: Thank you. Your answer might not be what I wanted to hear but is helpful non the least.